# how do I stop a website from automatically logging me out when I'm using cypress?

Tags: javascript, cypress

I'm using cypress to automate testing at my companies' website, and upon logging in, clicking on any of the interactive elements immediately logs me out. however, this is only when I run it through cypress. manually clicking around still works. What could I do to fix this?

this is for a website built with javascript.

I expect the website to not log me out.

```js
describe('signing in', function() {
    it('Visits the safe and reliable sign-in page', function() {
        cy.visit('https://testing.safeandreliable.care/sign-in') 
        cy.get('[id="at-field-username_and_email"]').type('bcramer@safeandreliablecare.com')
        cy.get('[id="at-field-password"]').type('******')
        cy.contains('Sign In').click()
  })
  it('signs into the default entity', function(){
      cy.get('[id="help-text-board"]').click({force:true})
      cy.wait(9000)
  })
})
```

Answer (score 4):

What you should know is that Cypress clears the state of browser every time it starts a new `it()`. So something what is done in the first `it()` is not now in the second `it()`. In your case, the login is in the first it, in the second it the application is not logged in anymore. To take care that Cypress stays logged in, you should move the login step to a `before()` or a `beforeEach()` (depends wether you want to login once per describe or per every it.

Following your post it seems you like it to login once and stay logged in, so the `before()` does the job for you. Your code would look like this:

```js
describe('signing in', function() {
  before('Logijn to the application', function() {
    cy.visit('https://testing.safeandreliable.care/sign-in')
    cy.get('[id="at-field-username_and_email"]').type('bcramer@safeandreliablecare.com')
    cy.get('[id="at-field-password"]').type('******')
    cy.contains('Sign In').click()
  })
  it('signs into the default entity', function(){
    cy.get('[id="help-text-board"]').click({force:true})
    cy.wait(9000)
  })
  it('next test', function () {
    // do other test but still logged in
  })
})
```

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't work. it logs me out upon interacting with any of the elements on the front page, and the console says "key 'project: en" returned an object instead of a string" and "session is not defined at <anonymous>:1:1"

Comment: check, I'm out of clues. But it seems that Vangelisz Ketipisz has added an answer which should help you further

Comment: @Mr.J. This worked for me. I kept getting a 302 redirect that was sending me to my login page even after authenticating. Based on your advice I realized that I had the login and redirect logic in separate `it()` tests. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the following (among with the other changes proposed in https://stackoverflow.com/a/56593040/8928727):

```
beforeEach(() => {
        Cypress.Cookies.preserveOnce('whatever session id')
    })
```

If the above is missing you would still have your cookies deleted between tests, and in this case that's not what you want. Read more here: https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/cookies.html#Preserve-Once

Answer (score 2):

Install this on your project's devDependencies:

`npm i --save-dev cypress-localstorage-commands`

Add this at the top of your Cypress' support file (in `cypress/support/e2e.js` ):

`import "cypress-localstorage-commands"`

In the `cypress.config.js` file add this like:

```
module.exports = {
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      require("cypress-localstorage-commands/plugin")(on, config)
      return config
    }
  }
}
```

Then you need to add this in `before` hook:

`cy.clearLocalStorageSnapshot()`

In `beforeEach` hook:

`cy.restoreLocalStorage()`

At last add this in `afterEach` hook:

`cy.saveLocalStorage()`

For details https://dev.to/javierbrea/how-to-preserve-localstorage-between-cypress-tests-19o1

Answer (score 0):

**Cypress 13** has **[session](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/session) handling**. With that you can solve the problem of using to much time, by logging in again and again.

I put this in a custom cypress command to reuse it:

```
require('cypress-plugin-tab');

export function login() {
    loginWith(Cypress.env('user'), Cypress.env('password'));
}

function loginWith(user, password) {
    cy.session(
        [user, password],
        () => {
            cy.visit('/auth/login');

            cy.get('#user_name').type(user);
            cy.get('#user_password').type(password);

            cy.get('#user_login_submit').click();
            cy.url().should('contain', '/main');
        },
        {
            cacheAcrossSpecs: true,
        },
    );
}
```