# Automatically logged out while interacting with elements after login in Cypress

Tags: javascript, automation, cypress

Automation Testing using Cypress + JavaScript

**Issue**

I am unable to stay logged in after login while running my script. A few seconds after logging in, it redirects me to a login page.

**Expected Result**

I want to log in until the entire script runs.

Please find below code I used:

```
LoginPage.js
```

```
//Page objects and functions for login page 

class LoginPage{
    
    navigate() {
        cy.visit('stageURL')
    }

    firstLogin(){
        //cy.wait(10000)
        cy.get('.MuiButton-root', {timeout: 30000})
            .should('be.visible')
            .and('be.enabled')
            .and('have.text', 'Sign In')
            .click()
    }

    enterEmail(username) {
        cy.get('#username')
            .clear()
            .type(username)
        return this
    }

    enterPassword(pswd) {
        cy.get('#password')
            .clear()
            .type(pswd)
        return this
    }

    submit() {
        cy.get('#kc-login').click()
    }

}
export default LoginPage
```

```
LoginSpec.js
```

```
/// <reference types="cypress" />

import LoginPage from "./PageObjects/LoginPage"
describe("Cypress POM Test Suite", function () {
    before(function () {
        cy.fixture('credentials').then(function (testdata) {
            this.testdata = testdata
        })
    })
    it("Login with valid credentials", function () {
        const login = new LoginPage();
        login.navigate();
        login.firstLogin();
        login.enterEmail(this.testdata.username)
        login.enterPassword(this.testdata.password)
        login.submit();
    });
});
```

```
Suite.js
```

```
import './LoginSpec'
import './SitesSpec'
import './LogoutSpec'
```

I run a Suite.js file. (I didn't attach other files here except login. Let me know if you require for solution)

*What I tried:*

I tried both of available options on [how do I stop a website from automatically logging me out when I'm using cypress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56583039/how-do-i-stop-a-website-from-automatically-logging-me-out-when-im-using-cypress). But it's not working for me.

Any solution? Thanks!

**Note:** It's working fine on my colleague's machine. I am using Windows 10

Comment: That could be anything - why do you expect someone to know why your app is rejecting the login?

Comment: My app is not rejecting me to log in. It's logged in successfully but redirects me to a login page within 5 seconds. This same issue is also posted by other users and tried the same but not working for me. Thanks!

Comment: So it's rejecting you after 5 seconds - the point is, there's nothing in the test that's doing that, so how can it be solved?

Comment: Also, what happens in the runner? How do you know it's rejecting after 5 seconds? The last command is submit, then the test finishes.

Comment: I am running a 'suite. js' which I forgot to attach here. after login, it navigates to elsewhere. Let me update my script. Thanks!

Comment: Cheers, appreciate the effort

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thank you guys for your efforts!

When I used cy.session() it was giving me an error for `experimentalsessionandorigin`. After enabling `experimentalsessionandorigin:true`, it was showing me another error for `testIsolation`. But adding `testIsolation:false` came with a new error which resolved by updating a Cypress.

In short, the following steps fix my problem.

1. Upgrade cypress - `"cypress": "^13.3.0"`
2. Add `testIsolation: false` inside `cypress.config.js` file

```
module.exports = defineConfig({
  
  video: true,
   
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      // implement node event listeners here
    },
    chromeWebSecurity: false,
    testIsolation: false,
    specPattern: 'cypress/integration/examples/*.js'
  },
  
});
```

Here is the link where I found the solution: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/24497

You can find more information from [Cypress documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/test-isolation#Quick-Comparison).

Thanks!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Let me try. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The logout is happening as soon as you run the second spec. That's because Cypress clears down data between tests.

If you follow the documentation at [Cypress cy.session()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/session#Examples), you should find the first example is close to what you currently do.

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('login', (username, password) => {
  cy.session([username, password], () => {
    cy.visit('/login')
    cy.get('[data-test=name]').type(username)
    cy.get('[data-test=password]').type(password)
    cy.get('form').contains('Log In').click()
    cy.url().should('contain', '/login-successful')
  })
})
```

Note, the login would be called before *every* test, but `cy.session()` does not run it on every call. On 2nd and 3rd calls it uses cached data to reinstate the login.

Comment: I write down your code at 'commands.js' file
`Cypress.Commands.add('loginTest', (username, password) => {
   cy.session([username, password], () => {
       const login = new LoginPage()
       login.navigate();
       login.firstLogin();
       login.enterEmail(username)
       login.enterPassword(password)
      login.submit();
    })})`
and add below line under LoginPage:
 it("login test", function(){
        cy.loginTest(this.testdata.username, this.testdata.password)
})
But find an error: CypressError: `cy.session()` requires enabling the `experimentalSessionAndOrigin` flag.

Comment: And then, you went ahead and enabled it I guess.